# SQL loop on duplicate row to combine into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, replace, duplicates

I have something to fix in my database here it is:

I have a table with duplicate rows like that:

[image]

the duplicate columns are **IDPatient** and **IDObjet** and you should never have both duplicate and that's why i put Key on both column but it's a bit too late.. so I have to fix this by combining these duplicate row into one without losing data and to put it in order.

**Example**, as you can see in the picture the column texte_1 contains each one a date 2010-11-25 and 2011-11-04. The date 2010-11-25 come before 2011-11-04 So i have to put 2011-11-04 into the column texte_2  of the first row and looping like that for each data I have in my row and to verify if the date is older or not. If yes, I have to replace the data in the row one with the second row, taking the information we have replace in a temp var and then finding a new column("Texte_X") to insert into the same row my replace data and validating at the same time if it's not older.

I can have multiple duplicate row in my table and I know looping in SQL server is slow, but would really appreciate a good solution to solve this here.

Here's a example of multiple duplicate row

[image]

Comment: You don't need to loop, you can just use `max`. E.g. Select the max records into a new table and replace the data in the actual table.

Comment: @alexandre do you want to delete the rows with older date and keep one set?

Comment: What if there are 50 duplicates, will you keep adding `Texte_n..IDRV_n` to the table indefinitely?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh Yes I have to delete the duplicate row i need to combine into one existing

Comment: @HartCO don't worry the data will not go over 10 (texte_10) the duplicate row have Idpatient or Idobjet different data

Answer (score 0):

How about a [MERGE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
merge mytable as t
using (
    select idPatient, idObject, max(texte_1) dt
    from mytable
    group by idPatient, idObject
) s on t.idPatient = s.idPatient
and t.idObject = s.idObject
and t.texte_1 != s.dt
when matched then delete;
```

Comment: I can't juste merge the data i have to order it too

Comment: Descending order of the date? What's use when you re going keep only the one with maximum texte_1 value?

Comment: yeah i just tried and only 11 of my 266 row have merged... and the merged row have delete my old data..

Comment: How many rows does `select distinct idpatient, idobject from tabl` gives?

Comment: 365060 rows. but not all that have to be merge. here's the query for the count : `select * from tbPatient_CarnetVac A
join (select IDPatient,idobjet from tbPatient_CarnetVac
group by IDPatient,IDObjet
having count(*) > 1) B on (A.IDPatient = B.IDPatient and A.IDObjet = B.IDObjet)
` it give me 266 rows

Comment: Is there a case where texte_1 is null or all the three columns match?

Comment: It can be null we have to check all column texte_1 to texte_10 same for all column

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function and your `ID` field to order the duplicates, then `PIVOT` to de-normalize the records, or self-joins, like:

```
;with cte as (SELECT *,RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY IDPatient,IDObjet ORDER BY ID) 
              FROM YourTable
              )
SELECT a.IDPatient,a.IDObjet,a.Texte_1, b.Texte_1 as Texte_2, c.Texte_1 AS Texte_3
FROM cte a
LEFT JOIN cte b
   ON a.IDPatient = b.IDPatient
   AND a.IDObjet  = b.IDObjet 
   AND b.RN = 2
LEFT JOIN cte c
   ON a.IDPatient = c.IDPatient
   AND a.IDObjet  = c.IDObjet 
   AND c.RN = 3
WHERE a.RN = 1
```

This assumes the `ID` order is sufficient, you could change it to your date field if needed. Since you ultimately want to remove the duplicate lines, you could either run this query into a new table, or after you use this as the basis of your update you can then `DELETE` records from the cte above `where RN > 1`

Personally, I would avoid the de-normalized `Texte_1-10` structure, and add a new field that's the equivalent of the `RN` field as part of the key.

Comment: Well it doesnt do exactly what I need... I can't only assume the ID order because you could have date_1 = 2015-01-01 and date_2 = 2013-01-01 i have to place it in order and your answer can only give me the the first column(texte_1,date_1,IDRV_1,Unite_1...) of each row

Comment: here is my answer

Comment: As I mentioned, you could change `ID` to your date field for the `ROW_NUMBER()`'s `ORDER BY` section. If you did a `SELECT *` you'd see that all fields are available, I just didn't list them all out.